# Can't get jsp date value to be formatted using css

Tags: java, javascript

In my jsp, I have the following:

```
$('#content').data("myDate", "<c:out value="${myBean.strDate}"/>");
```

And in my js, I'm appending this to css formatted data:

```
$('#sideBar').find("p[class=visitstatus]").append('<span class="visited">Visited on </span>');
$('#sideBar').find("p[class=visitstatus]").append('<span class="visitdate">');
$('#sideBar').find("p[class=visitstatus]").append($('#content').data("myDate"));
$('#sideBar').find("p[class=visitstatus]").append('</span>');
```

The "Visited on" shows up formatted, but the date (myDate) is unformatted. When I look at it using Chrome's Developer Tools, it comes over as:

```
<p class="visitstatus">
  <span class="visited">Visited on </span>
  <span class="visitdate"></span>
  "10/27/2014"
</p>
```

How can I get the date correctly formatted with the css?

Comment: did you define css rule for .visitstatus , the date value in your sample html is belong to visitstatus and you should define the format within this class

Comment: Hi @omer.dogan, I did, but didn't  post that part. Thanks for that catch though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
append('<span class="visitdate">')
```

appends a `<span>` element, not simple the the string `'<span class="visitdate">'`.  So the call to

```
append($('#content').data("myDate"))
```

then appends the date after the .visitdate span you just created instead of inside it.

You'd be better off to just concatenate the strings building the .visitdate span:

```
var visitStatus = $('#sideBar').find("p[class=visitstatus]");
$(visitStatus).append('<span class="visited">Visited on </span>');
$(visitStatus).append('<span class="visitdate">' + $('#content').data("myDate") + '</span>');
```